# Movie with highest rating?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Find the movie(s) with the highest average rating. Return the movie title(s) and average rating.

I tried this and stuck because I'm not able to retrieve `mid` if i add `mid, max(avg_stars)` then it will give `max` of every `mid`, I want only one `max` value.

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3ee1/13

```
select max(avg_stars) from
(
select top 1 mid, avg(stars) as avg_stars
from rating
group by mid
order by avg_stars desc
) z
```

excepted output `Snow White 4.5` and how can i handle if two movies having same max(avg_stars).

Comment: Not sure how much control you have over the business / UI case here, but I imagine it would be helpful from a usability point of view to also provide users with the number of ratings given. A single 5-star review tends to be far less reliable than 100 reviews giving 4-stars. Slightly off-topic but a point worth mentioning I believe. It might even be that just getting the top rated will return multiple single-rating movies, which might not really serve the original purpose of this query.

Answer (score 2):

This would serve your purpose perfectly & with performance -

```
SELECT
    Title
    ,AVG_RATING
FROM
(
    SELECT
        M.Title
        ,M.mID
        ,CAST(ROUND(AVG(R.stars),2) AS DECIMAL(10,2)) AS AVG_RATING
        ,RANK() OVER (ORDER BY AVG(R.stars) DESC) RATING_RANK
    FROM Movie M
    INNER JOIN Rating R
        ON M.mID = R.mID
    GROUP BY M.Title,M.mID
)RANKED_RATING
WHERE RATING_RANK = 1
```

You may have to play around the casting a little to suit your table definitions.

**Note** - If 2 or more movies have the highest avg rating - all would be ranked 1 and all would get selected. If you still want only one - you'll need to define a rule as to which one you want to be selected.

Answer (score 1):

Try this http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e3ee1/143:

```
;WITH CTE as
(
select r.mid, avg(r.stars) as avg_stars, m.title
from rating r
 INNER JOIN Movie m ON m.mid=r.mid
group by r.mid, m.title
--order by avg_stars desc
) 
select TOP 1 mid, title,avg_stars from CTE
Group by avg_stars,mid,title
--having avg_stars=Max(avg_stars)
Order By avg_stars desc
```

Output:

```
   MID    TITLE         AVG_STARS
   106    Snow White    4.5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TOP 1 MAX(m.title) AS title, AVG(stars) AS averageStars
FROM rating r
JOIN movie m
    ON r.mId = m.mId
GROUP BY r.mId
ORDER BY AVG(stars) DESC, 
          --Order by a seond column of your 
          --choice to break ties for AVG(stars)
         MAX(m.title)
```

Comment: Doesn't your SELECT TOP 1 only return a single record rather than all those that meet the criterion of having the top average?

Comment: Yes it does.  I'm not sure exactly how the OP wants to consider cases when more than one movie has the max top average.  So I decided to go with returning exactly one of the the movies with the top average.

Comment: Ah well, was an interesting problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can probably optimize or come up with something cleaner but this works:

```
SELECT m.title, AVG(r.stars) AS AverageStars
FROM       Rating AS r (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN Movie  AS m (NOLOCK) ON m.mID = r.mID
GROUP BY r.mID, m.Title
HAVING AVG(r.stars) =
(
    SELECT TOP 1 AVG(stars) AS AverageStars
    FROM Rating (NOLOCK)
    GROUP BY mID
    ORDER BY AverageStars DESC
)
```

Comment: Subquery in WHERE condition `(SELECT MAX(stars) FROM Rating)` will be calculate every time for every row. It's not right way.

Comment: I re-read and OP is also asking for those with max *average*. I read that as those with max, so I have given an incorrect answer too. Apologies. Will repost a corrected answer.

Comment: @NeilCresswell I want avg of stars not a single avg.

Comment: Fixed. Now all with max average instead of all with max.